# Find a pair $(n, k)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How could I find all the pairs $(n, k)$ for this equation. The most obvious pair solution that I can see is $(1, 1)$.
Using summation identity, I have:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6}$$

Then I thought of using cubic formula for $k$-equation, but it involved many variables. Any idea?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Do you want all solutions or just one?

Comment: @Moron:  I found references (that I didn't check) in OEIS that claim there are only four [or five if you count (0,0)]

Comment: @Ross: Yes I noticed. Apparently this is called Thomas' problem and the supposed proof: http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0022314X72900364. I got this by following your OEIS link.

Comment: I vaguely remember there is a theorem that says since the densities are 1/n^2 and 1/n^3 and 1/2+1/3<1, you should expect only finitely many solutions.  Maybe somebody will be prompted to cite it.

Comment: @Moron:  unfortunately I don't have free access

Comment: @Ross: I don't either :-( Just thought it might be useful. And if someone has access, they can perhaps post an answer with the idea.

Comment: @Ross: Isn't this just Mordell's Theorem that there are a finite number of integral points on any (nontrivial) elliptic curve?  Unfortunately a bit of searching for effective bounds turned up nothing that would be specifically useful here, but that was the first thing that jumped into my mind at least...

Comment: @Steven:  maybe so.  I was thinking of a result that was cast in number theoretic terms, though I can see how the elliptic curves could fit into this.  But I know nothing about elliptic curves.

Comment: @Steven: I believe the result in the paper is stronger. It tells you exactly what the solutions are.

Comment: @RossMillikan It sounds like you may be thinking of Darmon and Granville's work on the [Fermat-Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat–Catalan_conjecture).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only two variables involved.  If you want to search, you can write it as a quadratic in $n$, just try values of $k$, solve for $n$, and see if it comes out integral.  I find k=5, n=10, k=6, n=13 and k=85, n=645 as solutions as well with no more under k=200.  Then [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A053612) has no more and asserts the series is finite.  There are references for this claim in [A053611](http://oeis.org/A053611)

Comment: How could you find those solutions? Did you use a program to generates k, n or did you solve mathematically?

Comment: @Chan: I just made an Excel spreadsheet that did what I said.  Fill series will make the numbers from 1-200, then copy down is a powerful tool.  It works well when you want up to 2000 or so, then becomes cumbersome, but I find debugging much easier than with a Python program.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of Excel spreadsheet. Thanks for this great idea ;)

Answer (score 3):

Fix the variable $k$. Let 
$$k' = \dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}.$$ 
Then you get the quadratic equation 
$$n^2+n-2k' = 0$$
with the solutions
$$n_{1/2} = -\dfrac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\dfrac{1}{2})^2+2k'}.$$
Now you can generate your solution pairs.